# Is there any way to get gatsby-source-filesystem name in gatsby-plugin-mdx query?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm using gatsby-plugin-mdx to create pages. But I want to create different kinds of pages based on the folder they are sourced from with gatsby-source-filesystem. I made the name different in the gatsby-source-filesystem config but I can't seem to pass that along to the mdx node. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't query `allMdx` directly. Instead do query for `allFile` using a filter for `sourceInstanceName` field.

```
{
  allFile(filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "products" } }) {
    childMdx { ... }
  } 
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the childMdx field. I assumed if I queried allFile I would lose the transformed mdx output.

Comment: All transformed content in Gatsby could be accessible through the original sourced file nodes. This is something common for all transformers - remark, yaml, sharp, mdx, etc.

Comment: in onCreateNode can I create a NodeField on the childMdx node when a file node is created?